# How can we improve our close reason for software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'd like to see us change this off-topic reason:

> Questions seeking software recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

to be less about obsolescence than about *usefulness*. I'd also really like to include the following information as further guidance:

1. A link to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and its [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).
2. Some sort of indication that asking *how* to solve problems within a framework, or through processes or controls, is more useful to the community than asking for a tool recommendation.

I don't really have any specific verbiage in mind, although I plan to give it some thought. Right now, though, I think almost anything would be an improvement over what we have as our current close reason.

Brainstorming and constructive suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Typo in the title: "Imrove" should be "improve"

Comment: +1 for a link to softwarerecs.  I don't think I can add any more other than to say it is a good question but I am drawing a blank as to anything other than the current reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I'm keeping an eye this question to see if there is other feedback.

Comment: @MarkPhillips - The proposed reason sounds great to me.  If one of us adds it in the other can approve it.

Comment: Good call, +1 from me on the proposal and the accepted answer. It's tricky because as PMs we probably do have something useful to say to help people getting started in Project Management and seeking advice on industry-standard toolsets to help get them started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Recommended Wording for Closing Software Recommendation Questions

After giving this some thought, I came up with this suggestion for the new wording:

> Questions seeking software recommendations are off-topic here, but may be asked on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if they meet the guidelines defined by that site's [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help). For your question to be on-topic here, please focus on a concrete problem you're having with a framework, process, or control that can potentially be answered in a canonical way, rather than focusing on selecting a tool.

If this won't fit in the available text field, or if further refinements would improve it, your constructive advice would be welcome. Otherwise, I would hope that the moderators would implement this (or something like it) unless the community comes up with something even better.

Comment: I appreciate this post, and the updated link.  Looking for tools for distributed SCRUM management, and came across this question which was closed but had a lot of replies/interest.  Did *not* know that softwarerecs site existed before finding your post.  http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/choosing-a-tool-for-scrum

Comment: Ressurrecting this discussion: If a question meet the guidelines, we should be voting to migrate it... not to close as off-topic. One alternative would be to use the approach proposed by [Tomas no this meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226031/157692).

Comment: I left a few more notes on our [CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board).

Comment: Just found [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/30813/27189) and realized that it's not the first time I see this kind of posts in the community. Then after searching in Meta found this post.